# Window doesn't close when return to log in button was pressed

Tags: qt, qml

I was setting up my registration form for my project and for my return to login button I did this

for my loginScreen.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15
import QtQuick.Timeline 1.0
import "components"

Window {
    id: loginScreen
    width: 380
    height: 580
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    //Removing Title Bar
    flags: Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    // This function will close and open another window if the condition is met

    QtObject{
        id: internal

        function verifyLogin(username,password){
            if(username === "admin" && password === "admin1234"){
                var component = Qt.createComponent("mainScreen.qml")
                var win = component.createObject()
                win.username = username
                win.password = password
                win.show()
                visible = false
            }
        }
     }

    Loader{
        id:loader
    }

    QtObject{
        id:ld

        function register(){
            loader.source = "regScreen.qml"
            visible = false
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: bg
        x: 97
        y: 56
        width: 360
        height: 175
        color: "#032363"
        radius: 10
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        focus: true
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        z: 1

        Image {
            id: logoImage
            x: 90
            width: 125
            height: 125
            opacity: -0.05
            anchors.top: parent.top
            source: "../images/CCS.png"
            mipmap: true
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -102
            anchors.topMargin: 45
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            smooth: true
            mirror: false
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }

        Label {
            id: label
            x: 81
            y: 239
            width: 163
            height: 27
            opacity: 1
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Sign in to QUASS")
            anchors.bottom: label2.top
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 2
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottomMargin: 6
            font.family: "Segoe UI"
            font.pointSize: 16
        }

        Label {
            id: label1
            y: 45
            width: 201
            height: 125
            opacity: 1
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Queuing, Appointment, and Scholarly Services")
            anchors.left: logoImage.right
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 17
            font.family: "Times New Roman"
            font.capitalization: Font.AllUppercase
        }

        CustomTextField{
            id: idNumber
            y: 303
            opacity: 1
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.bottom: password.top
            anchors.leftMargin: 60
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 1
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottomMargin: 6
            placeholderText: "ID Number"
        }

        CustomTextField{
            id: password
            x: 60
            y: 349
            opacity: 1
            anchors.bottom: loginBtn.top
            anchors.bottomMargin: 6
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            placeholderText: "Password"
            echoMode: TextInput.Password

        }

        CustomButton {
            id: loginBtn
            y: 396
            width: 88
            height: 40
            opacity: 0.97
            text: "Log in"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.leftMargin: 60
            anchors.bottomMargin: 125
            colorPressed: "#090121"
            colorMouseOver: "#231a88"
            colorDefault: "#070a23"
            onClicked: internal.verifyLogin(idNumber.text, password.text)
        }

        CustomButton {
            id: regBtn
            y: 395
            width: 147
            height: 40
            opacity: 0
            text: "Register"
            anchors.left: loginBtn.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 5
            colorPressed: "#090121"
            colorMouseOver: "#231a88"
            colorDefault: "#070a23"
            onClicked: ld.register()
        }



        Label {
            id: label2
            x: 83
            y: 272
            width: 151
            height: 16
            opacity: 1
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("ID Number and Password")
            anchors.bottom: idNumber.top
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottomMargin: 15
            clip: false
            font.family: "Segoe UI"
            font.pointSize: 10
        }

        ProgressBar {
            id: progressBar
            x: 80
            y: 277
            opacity: 1
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            to: 10
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            value: 10
        }

        CustomButton {
            id: exitBtn
            x: 89
            y: 9
            width: 30
            height: 30
            opacity: 1
            text: "x"
            anchors.bottom: parent.top
            wheelEnabled: true

            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 157
            anchors.bottomMargin: -39
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            colorDefault: "#070a23"
            colorPressed: "#090121"
            colorMouseOver: "#231a88"
            onClicked: loginScreen.close()
        }
    }

    DropShadow{
        anchors.fill: bg
        source: bg
        verticalOffset: 0
        horizontalOffset: 0
        radius: 10
        color: "#40000000"
        z: 0

    }
}
```

For my regScreen.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15
import QtQuick.Timeline 1.0
import "components"

Window {
    id: regScreen
    width: 380
    height: 580
    visible: true
    color: "#00000000"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    //Removing Title Bar
    flags: Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Loader{
        id:loader
    }

    QtObject{
        id:ld

        function login(){
            loader.source = "loginScreen.qml"
            regScreen.visible = false
        }
    }


    // This function will close and open another window if the condition is met
    QtObject{
        id: internal

        function verifyLogin(username,password){
            if(username === "admin" && password === "admin1234"){
                var component = Qt.createComponent("mainScreen.qml")
                var win = component.createObject()
                win.username = username
                win.password = password
                win.show()
                visible = false
            }
        }
    }


    Rectangle {
        id: bg
        color: "#032363"
        radius: 10
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        focus: true
        z: 1

        Label {
            id: label
            x: 81
            width: 163
            height: 27
            opacity: 0
            visible: true
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: qsTr("Sign up to QUASS")
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 40
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            font.family: "Segoe UI"
            font.pointSize: 16
        }

        CustomButton {
            id: regBtn
            width: 171
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            text: "Register"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: address.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 5
            anchors.leftMargin: 55
            colorPressed: "#090121"
            colorMouseOver: "#231a88"
            colorDefault: "#070a23"
            onClicked: internal.verifyLogin(idNumber.text, password.text)
        }

        CustomButton {
            id: exitBtn
            x: 89
            width: 30
            height: 30
            opacity: 1
            text: "x"
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 10
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            wheelEnabled: true

            colorDefault: "#070a23"
            colorPressed: "#090121"
            colorMouseOver: "#231a88"
            onClicked: regScreen.close()
        }

        CustomButton {
            id: rtloginBtn
            x: 232
            width: 171
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            text: "Return to Log in"
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: address.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 5
            anchors.rightMargin: 55
            colorMouseOver: "#231a88"
            colorPressed: "#090121"
            colorDefault: "#070a23"
            onClicked: ld.login()
        }

        ComboBox {
            editable: false
            id: profileTypeBox
            y: 149
            width: 184
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            anchors.left: idNumber.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            flat: true
            model: ListModel {
                id: profileType
                ListElement {text: "Student"}
                ListElement {text: "Instructor"}

            }

            background: Rectangle{
                color: "#4d4deb"
                radius: 10
            }

        }


        ComboBox {
            id: courseBox
            y: 195
            width: 184
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            anchors.left: password.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            flat: true
            model: ListModel {
                id: course
                ListElement { text: "Computer Science" }
                ListElement { text: "Information Technology" }
                ListElement { text: "Information Systems" }
            }

            background: Rectangle{
                color: "#4d4deb"
                radius: 10
            }
        }

        CustomTextField {
            id: fname
            y: 103
            width: 166
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            anchors.left: lname.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            placeholderText: "First Name"
        }

        CustomTextField {
            id: lname
            y: 103
            width: 198
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 20
            placeholderText: "Last Name"
        }

        CustomTextField {
            id: mname
            y: 103
            width: 54
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            anchors.left: fname.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            placeholderText: "M.I."
        }

        CustomTextField{
            id: idNumber
            x: 20
            opacity: 1
            anchors.top: fname.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            placeholderText: "ID Number"
        }

        CustomTextField{
            id: password
            x: 20
            opacity: 1
            anchors.top: idNumber.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            placeholderText: "Password"
            echoMode: TextInput.Password

        }

        CustomTextField {
            id: conpassword
            x: 20
            opacity: 1
            anchors.top: password.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            placeholderText: "Confirm Password"
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
        }

        CustomTextField {
            id: contactNumber
            y: 241
            width: 184
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            anchors.left: conpassword.right
            anchors.leftMargin: 6
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
            placeholderText: "Contact Number"
        }

        CustomTextField {
            id: email
            x: 20
            width: 430
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            anchors.top: conpassword.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
            placeholderText: "XU E-mail"
        }

        CustomTextField {
            id: address
            x: 20
            width: 430
            height: 40
            opacity: 1
            anchors.top: email.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 6
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
            placeholderText: "Address"
        }

    }

    DropShadow{
        anchors.fill: bg
        source: bg
        verticalOffset: 0
        horizontalOffset: 0
        radius: 10
        color: "#40000000"
        z: 0

    }
```

In the regScreen.qml file, there's a rtloginBtn button that is set and connected to the function login, in which I put `visible = false` which is supposed to close the signup window after clicking the Return to Login button and opens the login window back.

Instead, When I press the Return to Login button, It did return to the Login window but the sign up window is still showing when it shouldn't be. And comes out as this:
[image: this]:

Comment: So what's problem? What window should be closed? What type of `regScreen` is? please provide [mcve]

Comment: I'll edit my post. Pardon me for not explaining it too well. I'm new to stackexchange and I really don't know how to properly ask.

Comment: Does changing the code to `YOUR_WINDOW_ID.visible = false` change anything? Are there any error messages in `stdout` (aka application output)?

Comment: not really. The message in application output is this and nothing else `16:58:57: Starting C:\Users\Markypops\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe -u C:\Users\Markypops\Documents\QueuingSystem\main.py...
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile`